# Ivy optional configuration mapping (source, javadoc)

Tags: ivy

Is it somehow possible to specify a optional  defaultconfmapping for ivy?

What im looking for is to specify in the defaultconfmapping to get all source jars, but some lib dont have source jars available, and those would be fine to skip.

something like:

```
<dependencies defaultconf="default" defaultconfmapping="default->default,sources(?onlyifavailable)"  >
```

is this somehow possible in ivy?

Else is there a way to only specify to NOT get a conf target?
ie:

```
<dependency org="org.lib" name="example" rev="default->!sources" />
```

The main thing i'm looking for is a way to define all (most) configuration mappings in the defaultconfmapping and not duplicate these mappings on individual items.
This means i'm looking for either an option to 'get but ignore if not there' or 'only adjust this part of the mapping without having to duplicate the parts that are still the same'
(one of the reasons is the large amount of dependecies we have)

Answer (score 2):

If you have an empty fallback, it essentially makes the configuration optional:

```
<dependencies defaultconf="default" defaultconfmapping="default->default,sources()" >
```

Comment: what part here is the default fallback you mention? the '()' ?

Comment: Yes. `foo(bar)` means "use foo, but if it isn't there, use bar". `foo()` means "use foo, if it isn't there, use nothing".

Answer (score 0):

Default configuration mappings are defined on the optional [configuration declaration](http://ant.apache.org/ivy/history/latest-milestone/ivyfile/configurations.html) within your ivy file:

For example

```
<configurations defaultconfmapping="compile->default;sources;javadoc">
..
..
```

This creates 3 configuration mappings (which I think is what you're looking for):

1. compile->default
2. sources->sources
3. javadoc->javadoc

Personally I prefer to default an explicit configuration mapping on each dependency, but that's more pendantic.

## Example

The following example generates an ivy report for each configuration and saves the source and javadoc jars in specific directories:

```
├── build.xml
├── ivy.xml
└── target
    ├── ivy-reports
    │   ├── com.myspotontheweb-demo-compile.html
    │   ├── com.myspotontheweb-demo-javadoc.html
    │   ├── com.myspotontheweb-demo-runtime.html
    │   ├── com.myspotontheweb-demo-sources.html
    │   ├── com.myspotontheweb-demo-test.html
    │   └── ivy-report.css
    ├── javadoc
    │   ├── junit-4.11-javadoc.jar
    │   ├── slf4j-api-1.7.5-javadoc.jar
    │   └── slf4j-log4j12-1.7.5-javadoc.jar
    └── sources
        ├── junit-4.11-sources.jar
        ├── slf4j-api-1.7.5-sources.jar
        └── slf4j-log4j12-1.7.5-sources.jar
```

### build.xml

```
<project name="demo" default="resolve" xmlns:ivy="antlib:org.apache.ivy.ant">

    <!--
    ================
    Build properties
    ================
    -->
    <property name="build.dir" location="target"/>

    <target name="resolve" description="Use ivy to resolve classpaths">
        <ivy:resolve/>

        <ivy:report todir='${build.dir}/ivy-reports' graph='false' xml='false'/>

        <ivy:cachepath pathid="compile.path" conf="compile"/>
        <ivy:cachepath pathid="test.path"    conf="test"/>

        <ivy:retrieve pattern="${build.dir}/[conf]/[artifact]-[revision](-[classifier]).[ext]" conf="sources,javadoc"/>
    </target>

</project>
```

### ivy.xml

```
<ivy-module version="2.0">
    <info organisation="com.myspotontheweb" module="demo"/>

    <configurations defaultconfmapping="compile->default;sources;javadoc">
        <conf name="compile" description="Required to compile application"/>
        <conf name="sources" description="Source jars"/>
        <conf name="javadoc" description="Javadoc jars"/>
        <conf name="runtime" description="Additional run-time dependencies" extends="compile"/>
        <conf name="test"    description="Required for test only" extends="runtime"/>
    </configurations>

    <dependencies>
        <!-- compile dependencies -->
        <dependency org="org.slf4j" name="slf4j-api" rev="1.7.5"/>

        <!-- runtime dependencies -->
        <dependency org="org.slf4j" name="slf4j-log4j12" rev="1.7.5" conf="runtime->default;sources;javadoc"/>

        <!-- test dependencies -->
        <dependency org="junit" name="junit" rev="4.11" conf="test->default;sources;javadoc"/>
    </dependencies>

</ivy-module>
```

Comment: Thanks for the elaborate answer, however this is not, what im searching for. I'm looking for some way to define IN defaultconfMapping that i want the source when available, will update question a bit to clarify the problem more

Comment: Please check my answer again. There is a "sources" configuration mapping that associates the remote "sources" configuration (available in all Maven modules) with the local "sources" configuration. Look carefully at the ivy "retrieve" task, it is being used to save these files to the "target/sources" directory.

Comment: Maybe i'm missing something, but my problem is when for example org.slf4j-api wouldnt java a javadoc target. Which would cause a resolve error. this resolve error i like to avoid this resolve problem without explicitly marking org.slf4-api as "*->default,sources" (so the javadoc would be retrieved if a newer version has javadoc)

Comment: @pvgoddijn I don't understand your requirement, sorry.